# Is there any way to perform Image processing using java with GPU

Tags: java, parallel-processing, gpu, rootbeer

I have got some code of image processing using *matlab*. For running matlab code we need to buy matlab license. But as per requirement of my project I have to use any open source software. So I thought I can convert the whole code into *Java*.

Also the present code is taking too much time for computing the result. For that I thought I can use *GPU* .

Can any one tell me a way to use java and GPUs for image processing or any other solution for my problem(I need to use any open source s/w and also parallelize the code).

Is it a good Idea to use **RootBeer**???

Comment: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/sumatra/

Answer (score 2):

There is a Java binding for [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) called [JOCL](http://www.jocl.org/) (OpenCL tasks can run on GPU).
I don't know much about [RootBeer](https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1).

Whatever the solution you choose, you will need to download the appropriate OpenCL driver from your GPU manufacturer (Nvidia, AMD or Intel). Note that the AMD driver can also use your CPU to execute the OpenCL kernels in SIMD mode and will work on any CPU.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I found an answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165909/how-can-i-use-gpu-with-java-programming]