# How can I use GPU with Java programming

Tags: cuda, gpu, rootbeer

I am using CUDAC all these days to access the GPU. But now my guide asked me to work with Java and GPU. So I searched in Internet and found *Rootbeer* is the best option for it but I am not able to understand how to run a program using 'Rootbeer'. Can some one **tell me steps for using Rootbeer**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Java with Nvidia GPU's (cuda)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866901/using-java-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda)

Comment: He gave examples of programs but not clear steps of executing. That means what jars I have to download and where I to keep them and so on....what is procedure to execute the program

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: You should *definitely* have a look at my answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866901/using-java-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda that was mentioned by MichaelS. Although rootbeer is an "interesting" approach, you should consider the alternatives, depending on what you want to achieve. Rootbeer tries to move Java Code to the GPU in a very broad sense. If you just want to launch some CUDA kernels, rootbeer may be an overkill. (And the *general* challenges, difficulties and caveats of GPU programming are summarized in the answer mentioned above)

Comment: So what do you want to say??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark Harris from Nvidia gave nice talk about the future of CUDA at SC14. You can watch it [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/supercomputing/2014/video/SC404-extending-parallel-computing-cuda.html).

The main thing that may be of interest for you is the part where he talks about programming languages and especially Java. IBM is working on [CUDA4J](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.71.doc/user/gpu_developing_cuda4j.html) and there are some nice plans about Java 8 features especially lambdas to be used for GPU programming. However, I am not a Java user and I can't answer your question regarding Rootbeer (besides the taste) but maybe CUDA4J will be something that suits you. Especially, if you know how to write CUDA C and need a solution backed up by a company like IBM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read about and it is something I am searching for. I am not able to 'Vote up' because of my 'less reputation'.

Comment: how can I use this. Does I need to download IBM Java or just some package from IBM and use it in SUN Java??? Please tell me..@Michael

Comment: @Saipavan579 as I said, I am not a Java programmer. However, it looks like CUDA4J is part of IBM® SDK, Java™ Technology Edition, Version 7 Release 1 so I assume that you have to download this SDK. I can't tell if it works with Sun Java. Please try and report back. Maybe this would be helpful for others as well.

Comment: @MichaelHaidl I think we need an POWER PC(A PC with An old microprocessor instruction set architecture designed by IBM) is the only machine that supports CUDA4J.

Comment: @Aadya thats to bad. CUDA4J looks nice for Java

Comment: But I am not able to install it in my PC.